# Cardinality of the following set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to calculate the cardinality for the following set

{x ϵ Z : Ø  ϵ x}

I think the answer is zero, but I don't know how to properly *justify* that.

{x ϵ Z : x ϵ  Ø} - For this it's easy to claim there are no integers in the set. But I'm confused about the reverse...

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your construction of $\mathbb{Z}$. If you are using the usual definition that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of equivalence classes of pairs of natural numbers, every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is an equivalence class that has $\mathbb{N}$ many elements. Thus $\emptyset \notin z$ for any $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

This answer depends highly on your particular construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ and in fact it is not hard to see that for any $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\mathbb{N}\}$ you can construct an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : \emptyset \in x\}$ has $n$ elements.